# Couldn't match expected type `HandlerT...' with actual type `IO String'

Tags: haskell, yesod

Trying to make a yesod app (without stack, and `yesod init`) and when ever I compile it I run into this monad error. I know these issues are common, but I've never seen anyone ask this question with these specific types (i.e. HandlerT and IO String). Here's all my code, so I think it should be easy enough for someone to test this. Also I'm using GHC 7.10.3, which is a little older, but I don't think my issue has anything to do with the compiler version.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3
```

Here's the compiler error message:

```
$ ghc -o yesod_test yesod_monad_test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( yesod_monad_test.hs, yesod_monad_test.o )

yesod_monad_test.hs:25:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `HandlerT HelloWorld IO Text'
                with actual type `IO String'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: snippet <- readFile temp
    In the expression:
      do { let temp = "posts/" ++ title ++ ".html";
           snippet <- readFile temp;
           defaultLayout
             ((asWidgetT . toWidget) (toHtml (preEscapedText snippet))) }
```

And here's my code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns          #-}

import Yesod
import Network.Wai           (pathInfo, rawPathInfo, requestMethod, responseLBS)
import Data.Text             (Text)
import Text.Blaze            (preEscapedText)
import Control.Exception     (IOException, try)
import Control.Monad         (when)

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
 /post/#String PostR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getPostR :: String -> Handler Html
getPostR title = do
   let temp = "posts/" ++ title ++ ".html"
   snippet <- readFile temp
   defaultLayout [whamlet|#{preEscapedText snippet}|]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 HelloWorld
```

I'm surprised that this code doesn't work, since I believe I'm following the tutorial (http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers#routing-and-handlers_overlap_checking) pretty closely, though I'm using Strings over the Text type.

Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to perform IO (`readFile`) inside of a do block for a monad that is not the IO monad (`Handler Html`). I don't know the details of the `Handler` type synonym, but the fact that IO is present in its definition suggests it will support some operation such as `liftIO`, which you could use to lift the IO operation up to the proper place.

Comment: Basically, @amalloy is telling you to replace `snippet <- readFile temp` with `snippet <- liftIO $ readFile temp`.

Answer (score 4):

@Alec's answer was basically correct. Thanks!

> Basically, @amalloy is telling you to replace `snippet <- readFile temp` with `snippet <- liftIO $ readFile temp`.